# how to go back to previous page on click and reload with previously posted form data with php or js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, page-refresh

I have a flow like this

1. Order Form page (index.php)
2. Confirmation page (where email is entered) (place-order.php)
3. Success page (register.php)

All pages have the order form with display:none and can be called on click to display.

In the success page, if the email is empty, it says 'go back and retry'.

Now when I use history.go(-1) or window.location.replace("place-order.php"); or
window.history.back(); it goes to the previous page. But the browser asks the user to reload page as the webpage has expired.

window.location=url will not work as it will go the url and all previously posted form data to that page will be lost

I want the browser to go back to the page and automatically refresh the page without the browser asking you to do it retaining the form values as when passed on from order form

What would be the best approach ?

Comment: Showing some code will be helpful. How are you moving to next page? From submit (POST)? Are you saving the data somewhere?

Comment: @anu The form is typical html form with POST action / and input type SUBMIT...this is captured in the next page with PHP if(isset($_POST)) . I can post the all three page codes...but that would be too long. If you want I can post any specific part you may want to check

Comment: Are you saving the data submitted in first page?I think you need to save the data only when all the flow is successful. You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to hold the values till all the forms are properly filled. Using this you can also' retain' the values when going to previous page using `window.location=url`(load the previously filled data from localStorage)

Comment: I am using the POST variable that's all...Isn't this similar to session storage except for getting destroyed when browser session ends  ? Would this automatically resubmit the saved data to the destination page when window.location=url is used ? Also could you show a sample usage for the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the answer is very simple using the _SESSION Variable !

I stored the POST variable to SESSION['place-order'] variable and used

```
 window.location:place-order.php
```

in the register.php page to redirect and added the following code to the place-order.php page

```
if(isset($_POST['clothessub']) || $_SESSION['placeorder']){
    if(empty($_POST)){$_POST=$_SESSION['placeorder'];}  
    //Do my stuff
}
```